# Creating a window just to get its framebuffer?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, framebuffer, raytracing

I've been writing this small ray-tracing engine in C/C++, and so far I've got basic functionality, where the finished image gets written to an image. However, I want to be able to create a window and get low-level access to its framebuffer. Is there a way I can do this in Windows without using any external library such as SDL3 or MiniFB?

Comment: It would be reinvent the wheel but in a very harder level
As someone who doesn't like to use libraries, I'm still using OpenGL (the most low-level i could get) to render stuff.  ___ 
Recreating something like that would take too many time for a 100 years living creature (unless you're an elf). ___

I know it seems to be something easy like, just get to a location in memory and place there the pixels to be treated as a pixel buffer, but aparently, it's not like tha

Comment: @alaanvv But it's quite easy to do in the kernel space, why is it made harder in userland when it comes to writing to framebuffers?

Comment: well, I searched a little bit here and it seems that the really hard part is that each operational system will require use of a completely different API. So, if you don't want it to run on other computers, I think it would be a good adventure to code it yourself

Comment: This not hard, you can use DXGI and Direct2D and you'll get access to the GPU. Create a swapchain on a HWND (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforhwnd) and then you can get the back buffers on it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-getbuffer). Check Direct2D samples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/d2d-samples

Comment: SDL is low level enough that you'll still feel enough accomplishment when getting things done with it, while at the same time not exposing yourself to the mess that is WinAPI, and keeping your apps portable (your future self will thank you when/if you decide to move away from Windows).

Comment: I'm not aware of an API that grants you low-level access to a window's "frame buffer." GDI is as low as you get with a regular window. If you want to go lower than that, you'll have to create and manage the frame buffer yourself (as Simon explained [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742555/creating-a-window-just-to-get-its-framebuffer#comment137056787_77742555)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use WinAPI to create a Window.

Here is an example of a Window with a button:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Defines

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // no MFC

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Header

#include <windows.h>
#include <TCHAR.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
HWND g_hwndButton = 0;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Event Handler
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;


        case WM_COMMAND:
            {
                if (HIWORD(wparam) == BN_CLICKED &&
                    (HWND) lparam == g_hwndButton)
                {
                    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                }
                return 0;
            }
            

        default: break;
    }

    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam));
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdline, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX winclass;
    winclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    winclass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_DBLCLKS;
    winclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    winclass.cbClsExtra = 0; // extra class info space
    winclass.cbWndExtra = 0; // extra window info space
    winclass.hInstance = hInstance; // assign the application instance
    winclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    winclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    winclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    winclass.lpszMenuName = NULL; // the name of the menu to attach
    winclass.lpszClassName = __T("WINCLASS1"); // the name of the class itself
    winclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&winclass);
    HWND hwnd;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(  NULL,
                            __T("WINCLASS1"),
                            __T("Window Title"),
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                            0,
                            0,
                            200,
                            200,
                            NULL, // handle to parent
                            NULL, // handle to menu
                            hInstance, // instance of this application
                            NULL);

    if(hwnd==NULL)
        return -10;

    g_hwndButton = CreateWindow(__T("BUTTON"), __T("My Button"), WS_CHILD |
    WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 20, 20, 100, 20, hwnd, NULL, hInstance,
    NULL);

    //UpdateWindow();

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // translate any accelerator keys
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        // send the message to the window proc
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of a button you need a kind of canvas where you can draw. One way is to use WinAPI + GDI for this.

```
UINT                    *BitmapBytes;
BITMAPINFO              BitmapInfo;
BITMAPINFOHEADER        BitmapInfoHeader;
HDC                     BitmapHDC;
HBITMAP                 BitmapHandle;

BitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BitmapInfo);
BitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = width;
BitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = height;
BitmapInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
BitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = 32;
BitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
BitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
BitmapInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
BitmapInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
BitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
BitmapInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
BitmapInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;

BitmapInfo.bmiHeader = BitmapInfoHeader;

BitmapHDC    = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 
    
BitmapHandle = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &BitmapInfo, 
                                0, (void**)&BitmapBytes, NULL, 0);

SelectObject(BitmapHDC, BitmapHandle);
```

Your bitmap class could look like this:

```
class BitmapDIBUncompressed32Bit
{
public:
    BitmapDIBUncompressed32Bit(int width, int height);
    BitmapDIBUncompressed32Bit(HDC hdc, int width, int height);
    int getWidth() const;
    int getHeight() const;

    virtual ~BitmapDIBUncompressed32Bit();

    void Release();
    
    HDC getHDC();

    UINT * getBytes() const;

    operator UINT * () { return BitmapBytes; };

private:
    UINT                    *BitmapBytes;
    BITMAPINFO              BitmapInfo;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER        BitmapInfoHeader;
    HDC                     BitmapHDC;
    HBITMAP                 BitmapHandle;
};
```

Your canvas can then make use of this bitmap. A canvas class could look like this:

```
class Canvas : public Component
{
public:
    Canvas();
    
    void setPixel(int x, int y, int color);


    void paint();

    void clear();

    virtual ~Canvas();

private:    

    void create(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInstance);

    BitmapDIBUncompressed32Bit  Bitmap;
    static int NumOfRegisteredWindows;
};
```

The implementation of the paint method:

```
void Canvas::paint()
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
    HDC hdcWindow = GetWindowDC(m_hWnd);

    BitBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, m_Size.getWidth(), m_Size.getHeight(), Bitmap.getHDC(), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, hdcWindow);
    EndPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
}
```

How the canvas is created:

```
void Canvas::create(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS wndcls;
    wndcls.style            = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wndcls.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC)WindowsManager::windowEventsProcessor;
    wndcls.cbClsExtra       = wndcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndcls.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wndcls.hIcon            = NULL;
    wndcls.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndcls.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_3DFACE + 1);
    wndcls.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    
    NumOfRegisteredWindows++;
    string UniqueClassName =  "UniqueClassNameID_Canvas_" + String::IntToString(NumOfRegisteredWindows);
    wndcls.lpszClassName    = UniqueClassName.c_str();
    
    if(RegisterClass(&wndcls) == 0)
        cout<<"shit happens"<<endl;

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,UniqueClassName.c_str(), "YourCanvas", WS_CHILD |
    WS_VISIBLE, 20, 20, 100, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance,
    NULL);
}
```

setPixel:

```
void Canvas::setPixel(int x, int y)
{
    Bitmap[x+y*Bitmap.getWidth()] = 0xFFFF0000;
}
```

Have also a look at [PixelToaster](https://github.com/ColinGilbert/pixeltoaster/).

If you want to got the WinAPI + GDI approach you can also find more information in the book "Programming Windows: The Definitive Guide To The Win32 Api"

As an alternative, you can create a OpenGL/Direct3D/Vulkan renderer device an a texture object, and write to the texture memory an upload it.

You can also use [tev](https://github.com/Tom94/tev?tab=readme-ov-file#over-the-network). It provides a network protocol to write to its framebuffer. This way you get tone mapping for free.

Also Qt can be an option for you - you can use a QImage and draw it on a widget - e.g.:

```
class RenderWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RenderWidget(const CommandLineArguments& cla, QWidget* parent = nullptr)  : QWidget(parent), render_scene_thread_(cla), render_preview_thread_(&render_scene_thread_) {
        draw_next_frame();

        setFixedSize(100,100);
    }

    virtual ~RenderWidget() {
        if(render_preview_thread_.isRunning()) {
            render_preview_thread_.quit();
        }
        if(render_scene_thread_.isRunning()) {
            render_scene_thread_.quit();
        }
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e) override {
        if(render_preview_thread_.qimage_) {
            QPainter p(this);
            p.drawImage(rect(), *render_preview_thread_.qimage_);
        }
        else {
            LOG(INFO) << "Nothing to draw";
        }
    }
        
public Q_SLOTS:
    void draw_next_frame() {
        if(render_scene_thread_.render_state_ == RenderState::Rendering ||
           render_scene_thread_.render_state_ == RenderState::Done) {
            static Vector2i old_size = Vector2i(-1,-1);
            Vector2i size = render_scene_thread_.scene->sensor()->film()->size();

            if(old_size != size) {
                this->setFixedSize(size.x(), size.y());
                old_size = size;
            }
        }

        repaint();

        QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(draw_next_frame()));
    }

public:
    RenderSceneThread render_scene_thread_;
    RenderPreviewThread render_preview_thread_;
};
```